# easy order by in template

Tags: angular, templates

I, 
I would show à hours available, but the hours in not order by 
this is my template:

```html
<ul>
    <li class="heure" *ngFor="let heure of plageHeure" [ngClass]="{ odd: (heure%2 == 0), even: heure %2 == 1 } ">
        <a *ngIf="heure.unavailable==true" [ngClass]="{ red : heure.unavailable }">
            {{heure.afficheH}} - {{heure.afficheH + 1}}
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="heure.unavailable==false" [ngClass]="{ red : heure.unavailable }">
            la journée est libre
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this is the result:

```html
Lun - 1524434400

    la journée est libre

Mar - 1524520800

    la journée est libre

Mer - 1524607200

    8 - 9
    9 - 10
    10 - 11
    12 - 13 //is note 12 but 11 
    11 - 12
    13 - 14
    15 - 16
    14 - 15
    16 - 17

Jeu - 1524693600

    la journée est libre

Ven - 1524780000

    la journée est libre

Sam - 1524866400

    la journée est libre

Dim - 1524952800

    la journée est libre
```

in "mer" , the hour is not arrange by order, because i use subscribe:

```js
  
  //on décompose la plage sur une journée en paramètre l'indice de chaque jour dans _semaine courrantSemaine
  plageHoraire():void {
    console.log("analyse plage horaire .....");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.plageJour; i++) { //i est le cran
        this.isPlageReserver(this.debJ0H['debJour0H'],i).subscribe(data => {
          this.plageHeure.push(
            {
              "afficheH": this.trancheDeb+i, "unavailable": data //on check si une des plage son indiponible
            }
          );
      });
    }
  }
```

with angular 5 have it à easy to order by ? where i can easy filter order , in a template ? in my component ? or i can use heat pipe ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I would do sorting of an array probably on backend, but if you want you can do something like this on your frontend, directly after you subscribe for data :

```
plageHoraire():void {
    console.log("analyse plage horaire .....");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.plageJour; i++) { //i est le cran
        this.isPlageReserver(this.debJ0H['debJour0H'],i).subscribe(data => {
           this.plageHeure.push({"afficheH":this.trancheDeb+i,"unavailable":data});
    });
    // this is where you sort your array of object
    this.plageHeure.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.afficheH-b.afficheH
    })
}
```

Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

thank for reply 
i try this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarModel } from '../calendar-model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SemaineComponent } from '../semaine/semaine.component';
import { CalendarService } from '../calendar.service';

@Injectable()

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heure',
  templateUrl: './heure.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heure.component.css']
})

export class HeureComponent implements OnInit {

  parTranche: number = 3600; //par tranche d'une heure 3600 seconde
  trancheDeb: number = 8;//la journée commence à 8H
  trancheFin: number = 17;//la journée se termine à 17H

  plageJour = this.trancheFin - this.trancheDeb;
  plageHeure = new Array();// = this._semaine.courrantSemaine; si elle est vide pas d'affichage avec ngIf != 0

  debJ0H;//sauvegarde le jour J
  finJour;//fin de la journée

  constructor(private _calendar: CalendarModel, private _semaine: SemaineComponent, private _calendarService: CalendarService) {
    this.debJ0H = this._semaine.courrantSemaine[this._semaine.iBoucle];
    //console.log("0=>" + this._semaine.iBoucle);

    let resultat;
    this.isDayFree();//est ce que dans la journé il y a des RDV ?
    this._semaine.iBoucle++;//important d'ajouter cette incrémentation
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  isDayFree()//on vérifie si la journée est libre si true toute la journée dispo, si false on scan toutes les plage
  {
    //console.log(this._semaine.iBoucle + "==>" + this.debJ0H['debJour0H']);
    this.debJ0H['debJour0H'] + this.trancheDeb * this.parTranche; //le début de la journée
    this.finJour = this.debJ0H['debJour0H'] + this.trancheFin * this.parTranche; //on ajouter la fin de la journée pour toucheFin
    //console.log("DEBUT J=>" + this.debJ0H['debJour0H'] + "FIN J =>" + finJour);
    this._calendarService.dispoWbsRdv(this.debJ0H['debJour0H'], this.finJour).subscribe(data => {
      //on récupère les rendez-vous s'il y en a, s'il y en a pas il sera filtré avec le ngIF = 0
      console.log("array push plageHoraire---------------" + data);
      //data = false;
      //data = true la journée est libre, data = false la journée est pris afficher les plages d'horaire
      data ? this.plageHoraire() : this.pushFalse();//data = false journée dispo on passe à la suivante, data = true il faut analyser la journée
      //on affiche les plages d'horaires de la journée
      //  this._semaine.iBoucle++;//important d'ajouter cette incrémentation
    }, (error) => {
    });
  }

  pushFalse(): void {
    console.log("journee libre  , analyse terminé !!!");
    this.plageHeure.push(
      {
        "afficheH": this.trancheDeb, "unavailable": false //on check si une des plage son indiponible
      }
    );

  }

  //on décompose la plage sur une journée en paramètre l'indice de chaque jour dans _semaine courrantSemaine
  plageHoraire(): void {
    console.log("analyse plage horaire .....");
    for (let i = 0; i < this.plageJour; i++) { //i est le cran
      this.isPlageReserver(this.debJ0H['debJour0H'], i).subscribe(data => {
        this.plageHeure.push(
          {
            "afficheH": this.trancheDeb + i, "unavailable": data //on check si une des plage son indiponible
          }
        );
      });
    }
    console.log(this.plageHeure + "UNSORT====");

    this.plageHeure.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.afficheH - b.afficheH
    });
    console.log(this.plageHeure + "====SORT");
  }

  isPlageReserver(debutJ0, cran) {//debutJO est le timestamps du jours à 0H qu'on test , cran et la tranche d'1 heure
    //timestamps depart = debut jour à 0H + démarrage journée 8H + la tranche d'heure x 1H   
    let debutPlage = debutJ0 + (this.trancheDeb * this.parTranche) + (cran * this.parTranche);
    //timestamp final = debutPlage + la tranche d'heure de la plage de la journée
    let finPlage = debutPlage + this.parTranche; //la fin de la tranche et le début de la tranche + la tranche ici 1H
    //console.log(cran+"DEB=>" + debutPlage + "***FIN=>" + finPlage);
    return this._calendarService.dispoWbsRdv(this.debJ0H['debJour0H'], this.finJour);
    //return true;
  }

}
```

my console log :

```html
array push plageHoraire---------------false heure.component.ts:43:13
journee libre  , analyse terminé !!! heure.component.ts:53:9
array push plageHoraire---------------true heure.component.ts:43:13
analyse plage horaire ..... heure.component.ts:61:9
UNSORT==== heure.component.ts:73:9
====SORT heure.component.ts:77:9
array push plageHoraire---------------false
```

the result is note sort